How do I separate a group?




I try to make an action that could give a paper cutout effect and it look right, but somehow my group always combine (The group 1 always inside of group 2). Is it because it has a same group name? I could give you the action if anyone interested. Want the action to apply just like in slide 2, but when i try to do the same with layer 2, it just combine with first group instead to be above it

Based solely on the screen shots, it looks like the action is designed to crop the selected layer with the layer below it. It would appear even the group below it. You can just open Group 2 and drag Group 1 out of it. Or fix the action.
